# How can I convert my Shapely polygon to a numpy pixel array representing (mask array)? python

Tags: python

I want to convert my polygon to a mask array?

```
from shapely import geometry
points = [[ 58. 115.], [ 58. 149.], [ 65. 157.], [ 67. 119.], [ 58. 115.]]
poly = geometry.Polygon([[p[0], p[1]] for p in points])
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = poly.bounds
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do that by using polygon from skimage library

```
from skimage.draw import polygon
instance_ids = np.zeros([height, width, instances_nums], dtype="int64") # the shape of 
your array
poly = np.array(obj["points"]["exterior"])
rr, cc = polygon(poly[:, 1], poly[:, 0], instance_ids.shape)
instance_ids[rr, cc, instance_id] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as Ram Max, but changed names and other minor adjustments:

```
from skimage.draw import polygon
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.random.random([100,50,3])
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype='float')
input_polygon = np.array([[10, 20], [30, 40], [15, 15]])
r, c = polygon(input_polygon [:,1], input_polygon [:,0], mask.shape)
mask[r,c] = 1
plt.imshow(mask)
```